# Obtain substring only by name in Oracle

Tags: oracle, substring

I have this data:

```
FlujodeTrabajoGrado22 SONIA XIMENA PARRA ARDILA U00053542
FlujodeTrabajoGrado22 ANDRES BECERRA DUARTE 1098456123
```

etc.

I use this select:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('FlujodeTrabajoGrado22 SONIA XIMENA PARRA ARDILA U00053542',
               INSTR('FlujodeTrabajoGrado22 SONIA XIMENA PARRA ARDILA U00053542',
                     ' ',1)
              ) 
 FROM DUAL
```

but I obtain this:

```
SONIA XIMENA PARRA ARDILA U00053542
```

the result must be:

```
SONIA XIMENA PARRA ARDILA

ANDRES BECERRA DUARTE
```

Comment: From the inputs and the query you posted, you are not obtaining what you are showing. The substrings will also include the leading space!

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions163.htm#SQLRF06302):

```
SELECT regexp_replace('FlujodeTrabajoGrado22 SONIA XIMENA PARRA ARDILA U00053542',
'^[^ ]+ (.*) [^ ]+$',
'\1') 
 FROM DUAL;
```

Use Regex pattern `^\w+ +(.*) +\w+$` in case you are not sure how many space ( or tab) characters separates the words as:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('FlujodeTrabajoGrado22 SONIA XIMENA PARRA ARDILA U00053542',
'^\w+ +(.*) +\w+$',
'\1') 
 FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need remove also the end of sentence

If you want a substr only method you can use

```
  SELECT SUBSTR('FlujodeTrabajoGrado22 SONIA XIMENA PARRA ARDILA U00053542', 
      INSTR('FlujodeTrabajoGrado22 SONIA XIMENA PARRA ARDILA U00053542',' ',-1) + 1)
  FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. The first `instr()` finds the position of the first space, and we add 1 to indicate the first position of the substring we need to retrieve. Then the second `instr()`, with the third parameter `-1`, finds the "first" occurrence of space counting from the *end* of the string (the minus sign means that), and we use that in an arithmetic computation to indicate the LENGTH of the desired substring.

This assumes you want to retrieve everything between the first and the last space character (excluding them).

```
with
     input_strings ( str ) as (
       select 'FlujodeTrabajoGrado22 SONIA XIMENA PARRA ARDILA U00053542' from dual 
       union all
       select 'FlujodeTrabajoGrado22 ANDRES BECERRA DUARTE 1098456123'    from dual
     )
-- end of test data; solution (actual SQL query) begins below this line
select substr(str, instr(str, ' ')+1, instr(str, ' ', -1)-instr(str, ' ')-1) as names
from   input_strings
;

NAMES
-------------------------
SONIA XIMENA PARRA ARDILA
ANDRES BECERRA DUARTE
```